# Не вижу html файлов

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование, jsx

Недавно упала задача, кое-что поменять на сайте. Но я не могу найти html файлов. Только css, jsx, js и css с какими-то web-pack. Сайт на centos лежит

В web новенький
Объясните как это работает. Пока я просмотрел файлы и нашел код html в js это понятно. Но как создаётся сама страница я понять не могу. Может как-то формируется из js файла ...

Help pls

Comment: https://learn-reactjs.ru/basics/introduction-to-jsx

Comment: так скорее всего там лежат уже собранные файлы для продакшена так сказать. не плохо было бы в исходниках смотреть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSX - это специфичная для [React](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html) нотация объявления древа компонентов

> Искать в современной верстке html это то же самое, что искать
>   ассемблер в серверных программах на Java.

```
function formatName(user) {
  return user.firstName + ' ' + user.lastName;
}

const user = {
  firstName: 'Марья',
  lastName: 'Моревна'
};

const element = (
  <h1>
    Здравствуй, {formatName(user)}!
  </h1>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  element,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Вам нужно копать в эту сторону. Вероятно, текущий уровень познаний не позволит исправить сайт без длительного изучения вопроса. React создает веб-страницу на лету, необходимость в статичных html файлах отпадает

Comment: Трипольский Пётр  Понял, буду разбираться.